# python - for loop over list - returns error "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, for-loop

I know there are many occurences of that question on the site, but the dozen or so that i read failed to address that simple problem:

```
for df, ind_source in ["df1", "df2", "df3"], ["investingcom", "bloomberg", "ft"]:
        print(df+" "+ind_source)
```

returns error value: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

What is the solution to that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for df, ind_source in zip(["df1", "df2", "df3"], ["investingcom", "bloomberg", "ft"]):
    print(df+" "+ind_source)
```